# Parsing multiple JSON Objects from a single file in PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing

I need to extract the Object id **total_time** from this file containing multiple json objects

```
{"alternative_names":[["",""]],"route_name":["",""],"status_message":"Found route between points","route_geometry":"qo{`o@wpslhBmFZwEpBgDzDeBlFWdGv@`G`CzEyBfIyEtEoNtEuMpAuHkAsCgC[mB{AgCuA{@uCa@}Cl@yBtB}@lDVhEcAtDmCdBcDx@iDDeDk@uBeBeB_CcGcXyFi^{Dg\\wBkP_Fs^wBiS_Ce[_D}UwAcKiBqIgI_TeLaUcMmP_IsHqf@_WyJeE}F`MkDjIiTth@y|@loBq^vy@mu@fw@cUxOco@r^gb@zRoOjPsBfMq@rMjBdPnEpKlEnH`J~Dvn@la@nd@pT|f@lLv_@pRzLbHnb@fUxc@lMnaC~zAncBxnA`kB|bB`|CbmCl]rY`xCzkCjwBzoBjxGl_G|fNhcMf~E~mE~pFt}EjbBlzAhvInyHfqDb~CblA`w@poAzt@z}@bb@diD~dBxtEjgCfjDljBpuAfw@bpGngDhqF~yC~g@la@v~@ni@rbAjg@jP`JlC`FNdDGdDu@j@eAhBa@lCLdCaCjI_BtCy@vA_DvF}qAf}Bof@l{@{CnFoKdR}mA`xBgM|TkJxPmLlSsf@|}@gf@`x@kOzXmEfGmSx^kf@tw@mDtL}k@r~@ykCjjEau@niAee@bu@uUl\\}DpFzCrCr|@dt@|NbLroBx_BdZlV|DbD`pBr~Anq@xm@r|@ls@|y@dq@}O`XuM`QcDhEoBgBeCCu[xXmBH","route_summary":{"end_point":"","start_point":"","total_time":824,"total_distance":15391},"found_alternative":true,"alternative_summaries":[{"end_point":"","start_point":"","total_time":886,"total_distance":14967}],"via_points":[[25.196808,55.273754],[25.139168,55.187702]],"status":0,"via_indices":[0,144],"hint_data":{"locations":["TdMLAP____8AAAAADwAAAA8AAAA9AAAAbAAAAOtwBgAAAAAACXmAARxpSwMEAAEB","4Q4AAGKyBgAAAAAACQAAAAAAAAAhAQAAAAAAAGUYAAAAAAAA4Zd_AfgYSgMGAAEB"],"checksum":326195011},"alternative_geometries":["qo{`o@wpslhBmFZwEpBgDzDeBlFWdGv@`G`CzEyBfIyEtEoNtEuMpAuHkAsCgC[mB{AgCuA{@uCa@}Cl@yBtB}@lDVhEcAtDmCdBcDx@iDDeDk@uBeBeB_CcGcXyFi^{Dg\\wBkP_Fs^wBiS_Ce[_D}UwAcKiBqIgI_TeLaUcMmP_IsHqf@_WyJeE}F`MkDjIiTth@y|@loBq^vy@ec@vfAyeAfcCok@vtA}Wtx@uS|d@skAvfCgExJgJpTqH|O}`@n~@wSve@qEhKkYdp@gB~DuUrk@_JdRsAhDmJlVqd@rcAuM|Zeg@zkAiKzUgIbS}B~EtDvBhr@`a@dQ~J|rBpmAj_CfyAlAzD^lDgHnOyQlg@w[l|@}Q~d@eBB}Af@mAdAw@bBWpBJrBn@hBaAjGif@ptAk^rmAoVxy@cHjPmC`H`E|Bp[xRpc@`ZfLvIzLlIreG~cEjrArz@rmAl|@lbDrzBjWlQ|xA~bAho@pc@d_@jWng@j^hNzJvGnEnPjLlAx@lgAhv@bGvCjkBvoAbjDr}BvfAx{@t\\rSfoDviC~zAjgAfOxIvAbAjwCtsBv|@|m@bD|BvL`Id_Dt|BtLlIxsAx_AfE~Crn@hc@rKvIh_BniApe@z\\xIpGtoBpxAtEdDrQrMzjChlB`~@lo@nwF`pE|jBl|AzFzE|DfDvDrCjKfJr`@n\\pLzK`nBzzAdO~LhaFxaEzCdCnLpKbp@ti@nIjHdRzMjo@tg@~MvKpwCtdClw@bm@z[bWfr@vk@zCrCr|@dt@|NbLroBx_BdZlV|DbD`pBr~Anq@xm@r|@ls@|y@dq@}O`XuM`QcDhEoBgBeCCu[xXmBH"],"alternative_indices":[0,183]}

{"hint_data":{"locations":["AXQDAP____8AAAAABwAAABEAAAAYAAAAIwIAAERwAgAAAAAADgyCAef7TAMCAAEB","bOsDAP____8AAAAAAwAAAAcAAADFAQAAFAAAAEJwAgAAAAAANQeCAdzdTAMFAAEB"],"checksum":326195011},"route_name":["",""],"via_indices":[0,15],"via_points":[[25.299982,55.376873],[25.29874,55.369179]],"found_alternative":false,"route_summary":{"end_point":"","start_point":"","total_time":101,"total_distance":871},"route_geometry":"{_ego@m}|rhBpBaBvHuC`EuArEUtEtAlDvEnD`MlDvMli@hsEfFzn@QlTgNhwCs@fKwBjF","status_message":"Found route between points","status":0}
```

And I am Using this Script,

```
 <?php

$data = file_get_contents('sample.json');
$data = json_decode($data);
$totalTime  = $data->route_summary->total_time;
var_dump($totalTime);
?>
```

But It gives me a NULL Output.Any help,would be appreciated?

Comment: Do you know anything about the structure of that file? Is not a valid json, so you can't do that straightforward. You may have to divide it first.

Comment: $data = json_decode($data,true);

Comment: @jothi no it's not working

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned, there are two json objects, then i suggest to read the file per line. Then for each line you can decode json or dump it. Hope that helps.

```
$lines = file('json.data');

foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
   // you are looking for first object
  $data = json_decode($line);
  $totalTime  = $data->route_summary->total_time;
  var_dump($totalTime);
 break;

}
```

Comment: I get error

 ErrorException (E_WARNING)
file({&quot;@id&quot;:&quot;AXWvvhh9is_Uqdy8ZoXZ&quot;,&quot;bucket&quot;:&quot;1409620614644&quot;,&quot;created&quot;:&quot;2020-11-10T01:21:12&quot;,&quot;startDate&quo........................

help

Comment: @jaberAlNahian I am guessing, the data in your file is not valid json. Either its html encoded or its not valid. Your code may help me understand further. Sorry for late reply. Also 'json.data' is a json sting containing file. if it is not clear in above example.

Comment: actually it was somehow a valid json file. all I had to do is $fileContent = preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $fileContent); After that, I could easily use json_decode method and all data was coming fine.

Answer (score 0):

The value can be retrieved by,

```
  $totalTime  = $data['route_summary']['total_time'];
```

If the json you pass to `$data` is properly formatted.

Comment: It's giving me NULL error again,should i use scan_dir() and loop it?

Comment: @BlackUser Probably your json is not in proper format. You can validate the json here, http://jsonlint.com/.

Comment: It's not validating because i have placed 2 json objects in a single file.

Comment: @BlackUser Then separate the json. And with the help of loop, pass the json one-by-one. First check two jsons separately are those correct or not.

Comment: `echo $data[0]['route_summary']['total_time'];` and see the output